# Linux Red Hat Library Dependencies question

Tags: command

I have to create a script that will download 8 libraries. However, on the server where we have all the libraries, I can only find 2 or 3 of these 8.

I believe these 2 or 3 actually depend on other libraries to work, so when I request via yum to download 2 or 3 of these libraries, all the 8 libraries will actually be downloaded.

I know there is a command to check out the dependencies of a specific rpm package:

```
rpm -qpR (name of rpm package)
```

My question is the following: is there a "reverse" command that, given a specific library name, will look for all the rpm packages that depend on this library?

Comment: Have you explored the `--whatrequires` option?

Answer (score 2):

The `--whatrequires` option to `rpm` will search for installed packages or package files specified on the command line that depend on the capability specified. If you want to consult uninstalled packages in repositories, you want to look at `repoquery -q --whatrequires` which is available from the `yum-utils` package. For the `repoquery` command to work, you'll have to have a formal Yum repository set up and referenced in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`.